# Proper way to pass an infromation/variable across QTabWidgets?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

EDIT: Changed title, few mistakes in code were resolved (now working properly)

The GUI I am trying to make will be a simple QTabWidget, leading a user straightforwardly towards the end tab by tab.

For now, I have three *.py files - main.py, tab1.py, tab2.py. In main.py is the main window of the app and function to run the app like this (simplified just to focus on my question):

```
import sys
import tab1
import tab2
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw

def main():
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

class MainWindow(qtw.QmainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tabwidget = qtw.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabwidget)

        self.tab1 = tab1.Tab_1()
        self.tab2 = tab2.Tab_2()

        # This is how I now passing the information from tab1 to tab2
        self.tab1.path_line.textChanged.connect(self.tab2.path_widget.setText)

        self.tabwidget.addTab(self.tab1, 'tab1')
        self.tabwidget.addTab(self.tab2, 'tab2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the tab1.py is a defined class for a tabwidget which will serve as an input data tab. There is a button to open filedialog, read filename, and write the path into the QLineEdit widget:

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw

class Tab_1(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.path_line = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.but = qtw.QPushButton('Open')
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.openfile)

        layout_1 = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        layout_1.addWidget(self.but)
        self.setLayout(layout_1)

    def openfile(self):
        filename, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Title', 'File types')
        if filename:
            self.path_line.setText(filename)
        else:
            self.path_line.setText('No file was selected!')
```

Now I want to in another file tab2.py use the path I got from qtw.OpenFileDialog. So the defined class Tab_2() looks like this:

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw

class Tab_2(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Retrieving the information by QLabel widget
        self.path_widget = qtw.QLabel()
        # Transform the information into string variable
        self.path_string = self.path_widget.text()
        
        layout_2 = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        layout_2.addWidget(self.path_widget) # The path from QFileDialog (Tab1) should appered on Tab2
        self.setLayout(layout_2)
```

My question is, is this the proper way to do it? Should I use MainWindow class as a "getter" and "passer" of the information like that or should that be implemented in the tab classes themselves? It works but I do not want to learn to do something bad way and eventually get used to it. I understand classes and their inheritance to some point (a lot of examples of dog classes or employee classes which I understand how it works but in my case I am confused.). In combination with GUI, it messing up my head. Also, I want to have each tab as a separate class in a separate *.py file to make it clear and easy to add another one in the future. I see, that it might not be the right way to uses classes but each tab will have a different layout.

Comment: This question is a good fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I did not even know about it. I will try there, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I found out that the best way to pass variable across QTabWidgets is, in my case, by class inheritence. For this idea, thanks to @S. Nick from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263594/proper-way-to-pass-an-infromation-variable-across-qtabwidgets/263707?noredirect=1#comment520787_263707).

I have main.py for the QMainWindow of the app and then two another *.py files, each containing a TabWidget class. Since I am creating imported Tab widgets classes in the main.py, the best solution for my question was to save a variable into the QMainWindow and then access it via Tab classes through the "self-parent thing". I am really a programming beginner, therefore I do not know if this is a basic knowledge or not. But by storing a variable into the parent QMainWindow class I can access it from any widget class created in the QMainWindow by including the "self" parameter. Here is the variance of the final code I used:

```
import sys
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw

#from tab1 import Tab_1
class Tab_1(qtw.QWidget):
    """ In this class I obtain a file path """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                 # + parent
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent                                         # + parent

        self.but_1 = qtw.QPushButton('Open')
        self.but_1.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        layout_1 = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout_1.addWidget(self.but_1)
        self.setLayout(layout_1)

   def open_file(self):
        filename, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Title', 'File types')
        if filename:
            self.parent.file_path = filename                         # + parent
        else:
            self.parent.file_path = 'No file was selected'           # + parent


#from tab2 import Tab_2
class Tab_2(qtw.QWidget):
    """ In this class I want to use the file path from Tab 1 """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                  # + parent
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent                                          # + parent

        self.but_2 = qtw.QPushButton('Load path')
        self.but_2.clicked.connect(self._load_path)

        self.path_widget = qtw.QLabel('')                             # will show path to file after the button-click
    
        layout_2 = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout_2.addWidget(self.but_2)
        layout_2.addWidget(self.path_widget) 
        self.setLayout(layout_2)
   
    def _load_path(self):
        self.path_widget.setText(self.parent.file_path)


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.file_path = ''                                          # + file_path
    
       self.tabwidget = qtw.QTabWidget()
       self.setCentralWidget(self.tabwidget)
    
       self.tab1 = Tab_1(self)                                      # + self
       self.tab2 = Tab_2(self)                                      # + self

       self.tabwidget.addTab(self.tab1, 'Tab 1')
       self.tabwidget.addTab(self.tab2, 'Tab 2')
             
        
def main():
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(400, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```